# Django symmetrical ManyToMany field on 2 columns

Tags: django, django-models

In my model, how do I exlicitly state that I want a ManyToMany relationship with another column to be symmetrical, so that when calling an object_set from each object, it can go through the same database table to find the relationships?

An example

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    employer = models.ManyToManyField(Organization)

class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Do I need to create a second ManyToManyField in the Organization class, in order to do something like

```
org1.person_set.all()
```

to get all persons employed by the organization and

```
pers1.organization_set.all()
```

to get all of the organizations a person might work for? Or will the single ManyToManyField symmetrically make the relationships?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything.

Because the `ManyToMany` is hosted with `Person`, it will be:

```
pers1.employer.all()
```

and

```
org1.person_set.all()
```